# MediatR .Net settings location

Tags: .net, mediatr

In a new project for me, a MediatR library was implemented. as far as I understand, this library is intended for microservice architecture. How can I understand where the request goes when the Send method is called?  Where can I see it in the settings?  Because this microservice is running and working somewhere and I need to understand where it is in order to deal with errors in it

Answer (score 0):

In MediatR all `Request` usually have corresponding handlers which implement `IRequestHandler <TRequest, TRequest>` with method `Handel`, inside this method you can find how your request is being processed. You just need to find the implementation of `IRequestHandler<TRequest, TRequest>`

Also, `IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TRequest>` in these classes you can find steps before/after request handler processing.